# Does Polly Bulkhead policy itself place calls onto threads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fallback, polly, bulkhead

I have the following [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/) policies defined:

```
sharedBulkhead = Policy.Bulkhead(maxParallelizations, maxQueuingActions);
resilienceStrategy = Policy.Wrap(retryPolicy, circuitBreaker, sharedBulkhead);
policyWrap = fallbackForAnyException.Wrap(fallbackForCircuitBreaker.Wrap(resilienceStrategy));
```

I execute the policy like so:

```
public bool Notify(IGrouping<string, TModel> messages)
    {
        var endPoint = messages.Key;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                policyWrap.Execute((context) => CallApi(endPoint), new Context(endPoint));
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

I want each call to `Notify()` to run on a new thread. So, my question is: Do I have to explicitly call `Task.Run(() =>` for a new thread, or is that automatically run on a new thread by polly?

Comment: Hi Nimish. We are going to need some background as your objective is not obvious from the question title or description. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to know if what I am doing is right? Do I have to execute the policy inside a thread created explicitly?

Comment: As api calls are I/O bound, I would not wrap them in `Task.Run`. You might prefer [the async version of Execute](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Asynchronous-action-execution)

Comment: If the call to be governed by the Policy (ie `CallApi(...)` in this case) itself is async, then the async variants of the policies should be used.

Answer (score 0):

> I want each call to Notify() to run on a new thread. So, my question is: [...] is that automatically run on a new thread by polly?

No. As the [Polly bulkhead wiki page](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead#operation) says:

> The policy itself does not place calls onto threads; it assumes upstream systems have already placed calls into threads, but limits their parallelization of execution

There is no concept of task-scheduling (using a `TaskScheduler`) within Polly (except, for completeness, in the very specialised case of synchronous pessimistic TimeoutPolicy).

For completeness, however, *all* Polly policies are thread-safe.